# Removing objects in arrayA if it's not found in arrayB - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Looking for some advice on my little project.

As an example, I have these two arrays

```
selectedItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
availableItems = ['a', 'c', 'x', 'z']
```

What I'd like to achieve is to compare my `selectedItems` array with my `availableItems` array. If the items in `selectedItems` is not found in `availableItems`, then it will be removed from `selectedItems`

result:

```
selectedItems = ['a' 'c', 'z']
availableItems = ['a', 'c', 'x', 'z']
```

I know I can easily achieve this with a couple of for-loops, however I'd like to know if there is a better approach to do this with Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this as well.

```js
selectedItems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
availableItems = ['a', 'c', 'z']

const result = selectedItems.filter(item => availableItems.includes(item));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed.